# Ensure a tab string is used as a template literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals

We have some data we need to write to a file, in a delimited fashion using Node.js.  We build a string to do this, as (simplified) below:

```
buildFileFromText(dataWeAreWritingOut, delimiter) {
 //...
 for (const row of dataWeAreWritingOut ) {
   textToBeWritten = `{textToBeWritten}${row}${delimiter}
 }
}
```

In the function that does this we pass in a `delimiter` parameter, to indicate how to delimit the columns involved (tab, space delimited, etc.)

When a string "\t" value for the tab delimiter is used we get a backslash and a t -- `\t` written to the actual file.  If we use `\t` then a tab character is correctly written to the file.

Is there a good way to convert the "\t" to its template literal equivalent without doing something a bit kludgey like `if (delimiter == "\t")...`?

[Edit] ok, I found out what was I needed to do.  The `delimiter` value was coming from a database column (queried using the Sequelize node library) and was a literal string of "\t".  When I compared it using ``\t` then I was able to compare the two correctly.

Comment: Code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n7f0526y/ The problem is that somewhere along the way, the tab character `\t` got masked into `\\t`.

Comment: (also note that you can use `dataWeAreWritingOut.join(delimiter)` instead)